# how to add indention policy based on special start and end word?

Tags: vscode-extensions, auto-indent

I am using vscode to program in C++ and I need a method that can help to auto do indention based on special start word ("intention-start", for example) and end word("intention-stop", for example). These words make no-sense in standard c++, but is useful on my machine.

example of original code as below:

```cpp
intention-start

int i=0;
int j=2;

intention-stop
```

the result should be like:

```cpp
intention-start
    int i=0;
    int j=2;
intention-stop
```

Comment: Are these `intention-start/stop` added later?  If so, I think this could be done with a macro.

Comment: Hi Mark, could you specify more clearly? I have checked some vscode extentions, like prettier, they seem not to support additionally specifying new indent label.

Comment: I was just wondering when you expect the indentation to occur?  You type `intention-start` and then everything after is indented until `intention-stop` or you go back and add the `indention-start/stops` later and/or on save the indentation are changed or you hit a keybinding and all the indentations change?  What is your desired workflow?

Comment: @Mark I would want all of them to work. But at least, i would hope that when I hit a keybinding all indentations would change. vscode has an inherent **format document **, and I hope that could work as well after some magic setting.

Comment: I can try for a macro to get the keybinding method to work first.  Are there always blank lines after `intention-start` and before `intention-stop`?  It almost seems a script may be the best way to handle this too.